# Dart type safety for map key, not working?

Tags: dart

With the following trivial dart function:

```
void main()
{  
    Map<String, dynamic> m = { 2 : 200.0, 'x' : 8.0 }; 
    print( "m: $m");
}
```

Why doesn't the Dart Editor / compiler complain about the int key type (2)?  I would like some safetly that all of my key types are String's, but this seems to run fine.

Comment: At least http://try.dartlang.org/ can't compile it and outputs the right error message

Comment: since others agree this is a bug, I've reported it [here](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15059).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug. Editor and VM don't complain, despite the runtime type being `int`.

But you can use a workaround until this is fixed:

```dart
void main() {
  Map<String, dynamic> m = {};
  m[2] = 200.0;  // editor complains here. VM in checked mode still works, for some reason.
  m['x'] = 8.0;
}
```

Comment: Hm, I see the editor does indeed warn about this, however its strange that this mistake goes unnoticed using try.dartlang.org.

Comment: @rich.e It's strange indeed. My best guess would be that try.dartlang.org uses a different analyzer.